# Waiting for websocket.receive consumer in django-channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, communication, django-channels

How to wait for a response from client after sending the client something using django-channels?

Whenever `Group.send()` is called from function `send_to_client()` and upon receiving the message by client, `send_to_client()` is expecting a response back from client which is getting received on `websocket.receive` channel.

Is there a way to return the `response_msg` in `send_to_client()` function?

Now I have reached [here](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faqs.html#why-isn-t-there-guaranteed-delivery-a-retry-mechanism)

`Sample Code for consumers.py:`

```
def ws_receive(message):
    response_msg = message.content['text']
    return response_msg

def send_to_client(param1, param2, param3):
    Group.send({
      "text" : json.dumps({
        "First" : param1,
        "Second" : param2,
       })
    })
```

So once the message reaches at the client side, the client will send a response back to the server which will be received by the `ws_receive(message)` function through the `websocket.receive` channel which is defined in the `urls.py` file,

```
channel_patterns = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    ...
]
```

Is there a way to do this so that my function would look like this?

```
def send_to_client(...):
    Group.send(...)
    response_msg = #response message from client
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are recieving via a websocket, I am not sure if you would be able to even tell if the recieving thing is directly as a response for your request. I would rather put an `id` variable or something in the ongoing request, and maybe ask the client to put that `id` in the response as well. That might require both the sender and reciever to know the value of id as well (probably store in the db?)

Also, it do not seem logical to be blocked waiting for the response from websocket as well.

Comment: WebSockets library for python supports something like `asyncio.gather(...)` in which you could wait for response from client. But I'm not sure if it's applicable to Django channels. I'm also looking for solution to this one. Tried with storing "correlation ID" but due to async nature, receiving back message and trying to look up ID results in NotExists error.